# multiple react apps (components) on the same page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to develop some basic components to add them to an existing webpage. I want to start with the default create-react-app. In the end, I will end up with src/FirstComponent.js and src/SecondComponent.js

I need to build both components individually. When I run yarn build i get a main.hash.chunk.js that hash the two components merged. Is there anyway to end up with two different main files? Is that a bad approach?

If I need to use a third party library, lets say axios, and I will need them on both components... Will it be imported twice?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to build the components individually?

Comment: You only need axios script once on your page. Everything else will be able to use axios.
What is the purpose of having two different files for you?

Comment: this is going to be into an existing webpage with his own custom cms. My client wants to include all the js code to run FirstComponent in page A, none of them on page B, and SecondComponent on page 3. That's why I need to bundle them separately

Answer (score 0):

```
If I need to use a third party library, lets say axios, and I will
need them on both components... Will it be imported twice?
```

- If the existing webpage you would like to plug these two new components into is a ReactJS app then you might want to consider making these two components  presentational components ([for more info](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)).  The axios request will happen in the existing web page and the data that each component needs will be available to them via props. I hope that helps somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I was looking for something like this: https://itnext.io/building-multi-page-application-with-react-f5a338489694